# How can I install package from private repository using docker

Tags: docker, npm, npm-install

I am installing a package from my private repository. I am able to install it using:
`npm i -S git+https://oauth2:XXXXXXX@gitlab.com/mygroup/acl-api.git`

I am using docker container but while installation process I am getting an error:

```
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://oauth2:XXXXXXX@gitlab.com/mygroup/acl-api.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

How can I solve it?

My docker file:

```
FROM node:alpine

COPY package.json package.json
COPY src src
COPY .babelrc .babelrc

RUN npm install  
RUN npm run gitlab-build

RUN ls
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "docker-start"]
```

Comment: Can you provide complete `dockerfile` and any docker commands you used.

Comment: @mchawre Sure, sorry.

Comment: looks like that migration(docker) from `node:alpine` to `node` solve a problem.

Answer (score 14):

You should add `git` and `openssh-client` and other packages if you want to the `node:alpine` to let `npm` pull the repository

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN apk add --update \
  python \
  python-dev \
  py-pip \
  build-base \
  git \
  openssh-client \
&& pip install virtualenv \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY package.json package.json
COPY src src
COPY .babelrc .babelrc

RUN npm install  
RUN npm run gitlab-build

RUN ls
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "docker-start"]
```